# Linq query results in the same references when initializing a variable

Tags: linq, .net-core, reference, entity-framework-core

How is it possible that all the initialized `Category = new bool[8]` are the same references?

Is this a LINQ bug?

```
var favorites = (from favorite in dbContext.Favorites
                 where favorite.id == userId
                 select new Favorite()
                            {
                                Title = favorite.Title,
                                Category = new bool[8]
                            }).ToList();
```

Iterating over the collection and writing to the console log shows me:

```
 Hash: 3688462
 Hash: 3688462
 Hash: 3688462
 Hash: 3688462
 Hash: 3688462
 Hash: 3688462
```

Code used to console log:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Hash: {favorite.Category.GetHashCode()}");
```

Did an equality test which was also `true`

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Is same: {favorite.Category.Equals(oldFavorite.Category)}");
```

Comment: Yes, they are one and the same reference. And yes, probably a bug - not LINQ, but EF Core query provider implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that EF initializes new instances for each entity if in the initialization "something" is done with a property of the queried entity.

For example, if `Category` was a class having a `FavoriteID` property, (and `Category` an unmapped property in `Favorite`), this query would initialize *one* `Category` instance shared by all `Favorite`s:

```
 select new Favorite()
            {
                Title = favorite.Title,
                Category = new Category()
            }).ToList();
```

This query would create `n` `Category` instances:

```
 select new Favorite()
            {
                Title = favorite.Title,
                Category = new Category { FavoriteID = favorite.ID }
            }).ToList();
```

Knowing this, you can work around the issue in a not too elegant way:

```
 select new Favorite()
            {
                Title = favorite.Title,
                Category = new bool[]
                { 
                     favorite.ID == -1,
                     false, false, false, false, false, false, false
                }
            }).ToList();
```

I think a better option is to initialize `Category` in `Favorite`'s constructor.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature. After all, it also offers an opportunity to create entities all referring to one instance. Well, seems unlikely that this is intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The code `Category = new bool[8]` creates an array of 8 Booleans, and initializes it with the default value for a Boolean. So all 8 Booleans in property `Category` have the same value, probably `false`.

Your code:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Hash: {favorite.Category.GetHashCode()}");
```

will print the hash code of the complete array of 8 Booleans, which is one int, not eight. Are you sure that you used this code to give you the 8 strings?

One reason that I think you didn't use this code for the output is because of the capital H in Hash, while your output shows a lowercase h in hash

If you have something like:

```
foreach (bool boolValue in favorite.Category)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Hash: {boolValue.GetHashCode()}");
}
```

then you'll get the same hash code value 8 times, once for each Boolean value in your array.

Comment: The 'H' is just a copy and paste typo. It tried this and all the hashcode was diffrent,             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                bool[] x = new bool[8];
                Debug.WriteLine($"hash: {x.GetHashCode()}");
            }

Comment: But getting the hashcode for the linq query response yielded the same hashcode for all items in the query-collection, i think @Gert Arnold is correct on this one.